# Do I have to use colspan for every row just for one row?

Tags: html, html-table, row, col

I am trying to make a table with multiple rows and one columns in html. All rows will have one column except for one. I know this can be done with colspan. But I dont want to write colspan for every row just for one. Is there an easy way to do this?

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td> 
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Structure:

```
[         Some Text          ] 
[         Some Text          ] 
[         Some Text          ] 
[Some     Text][Some     Text] 
[         Some Text          ] 
[         Some Text          ]
```

Comment: I think you can't do this without `colspan`

Answer (score 0):

other wise dont use table  use div

```
<div style="width:100px">
<label style="width:100px"></br>
<label style="width:100px"></br>
<label style="width:50px">
<label style="width:50px"></br>
<label style="width:100px"></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```css
table tr:nth-of-type(4) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

table {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it with jsfiddle using table border. I think there is a problem. I have to use colspan I think

Answer (score 0):

Puting an empty "td" inside "tr" will give a really close out put:

```
 <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td> 
        <td></td>            
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the cross browser compatibly, but here is a solution.

```css
td:only-child{
  display:block;
  width:100%
}

td {
  display:inline-block;
   background:#eee;
   text-align:center;
   width:50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table width="250">
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some text</td> 
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```